# SQL Server 2008 service stopped after certain period of time

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7

There is locally hosted website in IIS which has a database of around 250 tables and currently around 40-45 users work on this website.

The problem I'm facing is that the SQL Server 2008 service is stopping after certain periods of time (around 20-25 min). Then I have to restart it manually in in `service.msc`.

What is permanent solution of this problem?

Comment: Look in the logs, find out why it's shutting down. Not something we can help with at this stage.

Comment: error in my log 2015-08-25 13:53:40.82 Logon Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>] 2015-08-25 13:53:44.12 Logon Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38. 2015-08-25 13:53:44.12 Logon Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]